# Noob: i design a network for 156 computers/4 printers, need help in few things

Tags: switch, router, network, networking, idf

Sorry if this stupid questions: I just learn networking like a week.

Lets say company xyz have 39 computers and 1 printer in each floor, there are 4 floors, total amount of computers is 156computers and 4 printers, each computer connected to electricity including the switch and router.

In each floor the 39 computers connected to a 48 port Cisco switch, *each floor is a different lan.

-each computer with his own ip/Mac address, subnet mask, default exit.

Questions:

1. Do you connect the 4 switchs that in each floor to one main router, So if one Lan want to communicate with another Lan in the same company, and this router also act as a default gateaway to the interent or
   use
   More routers which connected and then connected to each other, to not overload one main router?
2. You have 4 switchs, each floor switch, let's say you connect 2 switchs to one router, and 2 other switches to another Router and then connect this 2 routers togther, the question is: do you connect this 2 routers to another main router to get to the internet, or the 2 routers, each of one of them is just connected to the internet?
3. The first floor with 39 computers and 1 printer all connected with cat cable which run to the idf small room where the switch seats in a rack? And the switch connected to a source electricity. And each floor have idf room in the same Organization

Thus is right?

4. Each router or one the main router that connected the 4 switches in each floor will be in the mdf room where is the demarc point for accessing the web?
5. Each floor with 39 computers and 1 printer which connected to a switch and this switch connect to a router, the switch and the router in the idf room.

Can you pls elaborate on what else needed to design a such floor, with 39 computers/1 printer....
Which switches and cables I know*, but other important things/parts, then I will understand how other floors designed/build, by understanding one floor very good.

Thanks

Comment: What model of switches and router are you using?

Comment: I just learn a less then a week networking, let's say I use 48 port gigabytes Cisco switch, about the model of the router I still do research, I just to understand the big picture so it will be more easy to dive to the details...

Answer (score 1):

> Do you connect the 4 switchs that in each floor to one main router, So if one Lan want to communicate with another Lan in the same company, and this router also act as a default gateaway to the interent or use More routers which connected and then connected to each other, to not overload one main router?

That depends on the router. Very often a layer-3 switch is used for inter-(V)LAN routing since they're fairly cheap and route at wirespeed. A router with a stateful firewall may need to be quite beefy for routing internal traffic, but that highly depends on the actual workloads and your requirements.

> You have 4 switchs, each floor switch, let's say you connect 2 switchs to one router, and 2 other switches to another Router and then connect this 2 routers togther, the question is: do you connect this 2 routers to another main router to get to the internet, or the 2 routers, each of one of them is just connected to the internet?

I'd place a switch on each floor (layer 2 is sufficient) and connect them all together on a layer-3 core switch which also routes between internal subnets (=VLANs). For WAN and VPN routing you then connect an appropriate router with firewall to that core switch.

Comment: Thanks Zac, I just try to understand the big picture so it will be more easy for the mind to understand the details,